# How can I integrate with a third-party API secured with oAuth2 in asp.net core 3.1?

Tags: rest, api, asp.net-core, .net-core, oauth-2.0

We're trying to integrate with an external third-party REST-API that's secured with oAuth2 but the service isn't really an identity provider, so I'm not sure what terminology I'm looking for. Obviously when it comes to looking at "asp.net core" and "oauth", millions of hits come up related to adding it as an identity provider but I don't think that's what we want.

This is how I would expect it to work, based on what I've seen in other saas apps:

1. User logs into the site
2. User looks at some "third-party integrations" page and clicks to add this one
3. User's browser is directed to the other service to login
4. On successful login, user is directed back and we have access to the bearer + refresh token which we store(?) and use.

Some use of this API is in response to user action (refresh to get results), but some is also just background work so I assume we're storing this information and using implicit flow to refresh the token for as long as we can unless it's revoked.

What asp.net core terminology am I looking for, how would someone properly describe this flow in oAuth terms? We're getting confused between authorization, authentication, providers, handlers, middleware, etc.

In terms of this third-party API oauth flow, in case people want to know, here's what's required:

- We call a specific endpoint that tells us the correct authorization and token endpoints
- We then redirect to the authorization endpoint, which presents the user with the remote service's login page.
- The user logs into the other service and is redirected back and the code and grant_type=authorization_code are provided via the url
- We call the token endpoint with that information to get the final bearer+refresh token

Comment: As you said, the API is protected by OAuth 2.0, do you know what is the API's Identity Provider? Google, facebook, twitter or anything else? As long as you figured this out, you can register your App in those Identity Provider then configure your apps

Comment: It handles it's own identity, no social logins.

Comment: if it handles its own identity, i think you need to register your application and get client id and client secert first. Does the Restful API provide a Provider for Asp.net core?